# Show duplicates of records that share same ID but different in another column

Tags: mysql

Trying to figure out the best way to return results when I need to show which records have more than one of the same `ID` that also have more than one of the same `TYPE` in another column

For example:

Table 1

```
ID
1234
5678
9012
```

Then I want to left join to show related rows to a table like this:

Table 2

```
ID     ID2     TYPE
1234   1111    id
1234   1111    user_id
1234   2222    user_id
5678   1111    user_id
5678   3333    id
5678   4444    id_id
5678   5555    id
5678   3333    user_id
9012   7777    id
9012   7778    id_2
9012   7777    id
```

I would like my results to be this for this example:

Results:

```
ID    ID2    TYPE
1234  2222   user_id
1234  1111   user_id
5678  3333   id
5678  5555   id
```

`9012` would not be returned in the results because the ID2 is the same in the return TYPE.

I need to return records that share the same type but also have more than one ID2.

Comment: What have you tried? A `JOIN` seems appropriate here, but you're much more likely to get help if you show you've made some effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Only thing I am able to do with my ability is left join to get the matching results for the two tables. I normally can group by and use having to get the ones that are duplicates. However, I am not sure how to get duplicates first, then get the duplicates of those duplicates.

Comment: Ok, show us that `LEFT JOIN` query. Presumably you've tried some `WHERE` clauses? Setting something up at sqlfiddle.net is a good idea for SQL questions as well, it allows people to see your table layout and make suggestions more easily.